# Run into a 500 internal server error when loading css and js in express

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I'm new to NodeJS,tring to replicate the program on the book.
View engine is jade,and I'm using Bootstrap.The static path is right,I think.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

but when I console it,it shows this,

```
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\express\microblog/public
```

the problem only shows when I try to visit the page in broswer,not immediately after I actived the server,and the error code is 500, like below,

```
Cannot read property 'lazyrouter' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'lazyrouter' of undefined
    at route (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\express\microblog\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:254:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\express\microblog\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\express\microblog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\express\microblog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\express\microblog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\express\microblog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\express\microblog\node_modules\express-session\index.js:489:7
    at C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\express\microblog\node_modules\connect-mongo\lib\connect-mongo.js:306:11
    at handleCallback (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\express\microblog\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:96:12)
    at C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\express\microblog\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:1335:5
```

but actually the layout.jade is correctly rendered,only the block content area shows the error.

app.js below

```
var settings=require('./settings');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session=require('express-session');
var MongoStore=require('connect-mongo')(session);

var User=require('./models/user');
var crypto=require('crypto');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var post = require('./routes/post');
var reg = require('./routes/reg');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var logout = require('./routes/logout');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: settings.cookieSecret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStore({
        db:settings.db
    })
}));
app.use(app.route);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/public')));
console.log(__dirname+'/public');


app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/post', post);
app.use('/reg', reg);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/logout', logout);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

app.use(function (req,res,next) {
    res.locals.user=req.session.user;

    var err=req.flash('error');
    var success=req.flash('success');

    res.locals.err=err.length?err:null;
    res.locals.success=success.length?success:null;

    next();
})

module.exports = app;
```

`
below is the link part of layout.jade

```
link(type='text/css',rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css')
link(type='text/css',rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.css')
script(src="/javascripts/jquery.js")
script(src="/javascripts/bootstrap.js")
```

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on paths. On Windows, paths are constructed with backslashes instead of forward slashes.

try changing this code

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

to this

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

using `path.join(__dirname, 'public')` will handle the slash or backslash for you.

Heres more reference for you. https://gist.github.com/domenic/2790533

Hope it helps.

Comment: no use. but thx. I've solved the problem by carefully rewrite the program.

Answer (score 0):

As the following code '/sample' refer the whole path to sample folder.(In app.js)

```
app.use('/sample',express.static(__dirname + '/public/sample'));
```

Then you can link your file as below, (In view file)

```
<script src="/sample/sample.js"></script>
```